# Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jdbc

In my springboot application properties file, I have set wrong passwword, and hence application fails to start.

But logs instead of saying anything about connection issues due to wrong credentials, says this:

```
Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata
```

Whats the connection between wrong credential and this message?